# Unable to resolve static resources in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I know this question has a lot of answers but i cannot solve mine so that is why i decided to put up the question
I want to resolve both jsp and html files. Below is my spring resolver configuration

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix("");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/static");
}
```

and controller class is below:

```
@RequestMapping("/testApi2")
@Controller
public class TestController2 
{
   @RequestMapping("/showHomePage")
    public ModelAndView showHome(){
      return new ModelAndView("/static/about.html");
    }

}
```

I have also attached screen shot of my directory structure, **it is giving 404 on every request**

[image]

Comment: The prefix is `/WEB-INF/views/`. The suffix is an empty string. The view name is `/static/about.html`. So the concatenation of all this is `/WEB-INF/views//static/about.html`. Even if the double slash is properly handled, that won't find your about.html file, which is under `/WEB-INF/views/static/HTML/about.html`.

Comment: Changing `resolver.setSuffix("")` to `resolver.setSuffix(".html")` might help you

Comment: yeah silly mistake , but still the resources inside html are giving 404

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should add to your web resolver config class one very special handling configurer:

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(

DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
configurer.enable();
}
```

This method **enables** static resources processing.

Answer (score 1):

After some efforts , thanks to lot of documentation on Spring , i was able to resolve the issue

I found a solution(searched on net) with which we can use **both JSP and HTML as views**

**Forget the question , below are the new settings**

Static resources (.css,.js,.jpg) are placed in **webapp/assets/**

HTML files are in **/WEB-INF/static/**

Here is my configuration file :

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix("");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**") //
            .addResourceLocations("/assets/").setCachePeriod(31556926);

}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Please note i have used `resolver.setSuffix("")` both HTML and JSP

HTML code :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/taxi/assets/css/theme-pink.css" />`

Here **taxi is the context root** , means name of the project

Now if i run the below URL , it will fetch the image or CSS of js

```
localhost:8080/taxi/assets/css/icons.css
```